# Javascript message box doesnot get closed after ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

aMy scenario is like this. I want to delete a resource. When I click on delete href I pop-up a javascript message box (delete confirmation) When The okay button is clicked my call is going to backend though ajax function as I want to capture the response of the backend.

This is the href

```
<a data-href="javascript:subscriptionLookup('+full.appId+');" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete" href="#">[Delete]</a>
```

My confirmation message box pops-up correctly. Then I click on okay button on that box. The resource is deleting but my message box don't get closed. Also I want to open ajax dialog box to capture the response. What would be the reason for this ?

Here is my ajax function

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


function subscriptionLookup(appID) {

     $.ajax({
                       url:'deleteApplication?appId='+appID,
                       type: "GET",
                       success: function (response) {
                           alert(response);
                       },
                       error: function(response) {
                           alert(response);

                       }

                   });
                }

 <script>
    $('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        $(this).find('.danger').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));

        $('.debug-url').html('Delete URL: <strong>' +     $(this).find('.danger').attr('href') + '</strong>');
    })
</script>
```

Comment: it is to open a new dialog box for response. But it does not open new dialog box

Comment: change showMessageDialogBox with alert and tell us the response

Comment: Did you checked the request in the dev tools(f12) ?

Comment: I have done this, alert are poped up on top of the message box, the problem is when i  click ok button of the confirmation message box it does not cloed

Comment: Looks like this is specific to bootstrap, you should add the appropriate tag to the question. And you probably need to show the html of confirm-delete (id="confirm-delete" somewhere on the page)

Comment: added confirm-delete